# PHP Page Scraping - cUrl Redirect Problem

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this link: https://www.bu.edu/link/bin/uiscgi_studentlink/1293403322?College=SMG&Dept=AC&Course=222&Section=C1&Subject=ACCT &MtgDay=&MtgTime=&ModuleName=univschr.pl&KeySem=20114&ViewSem=Spring+2011&SearchOptionCd=C&SearchOptionDesc=Class+Subject&MainCampusInd=. (It works fine if you access it in the browser.)

So I cUrl it, using this code:

```
function curl_classes($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  echo "NOW IM REALY GOING TO: " . $url;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  unset($ch);
  if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
  }
  echo htmlspecialchar($html);
}
```

---

EDIT

Okay, new problem. My cookie storing code doesn't seem to be working. I'm able to scrape this like as desired: bu[DOT]edu/link/bin/uiscgi_studentlink/1293357973?ModuleName=univschr.pl&SearchOptionDesc=Class+Subject&SearchOptionCd=C&KeySem=20114&ViewSem=Spring+2011&Subject=ACCT&MtgDay=&MtgTime=

But when I try to scrape the link at the top of this post I get: "Sorry you need cookies enabled..."

**What am I doing wrong in my cookie storing code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting that you do access the HTML. It prints the HTML to the screen, and that HTML includes code that redirects you to a new page.

Try outputting an encoded version of the HTML, so that the browser interprets it as plain text:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

However, looking at your actual code: please do not pretend to be Google. You are not the Googlebot, so your script should not say that you are. If you include any user agent at all (and I recommend that you do), make it reflect your identity, in case the site owner hits issues with your bot. No need to be shady :)

Comment: Hmm. That fixed the redirect but now it's loading a page for non-cookie browsers without the class info. I'd appreciate it if you could read the post edit.

Comment: @Pauly: Some users report that they need to use absolute paths for their COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE entries to work :/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're echoing the contents out in the browser, any javascript in the remote page will be executed. Presumably something is redirecting the page.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the javascript when echoing? Otherwise, how can I see what's in $html if not with echo?

Comment: just simply, echo the html in textarea :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the html into a file and then open that in an editor if you have annoying javascript. Or just disable JS in your browser.